# How do I generate random quiz questions and score them?

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
       ... questions here ...    ....Question 1....    <li>
    <h3>CSS Stands for...</h3>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" />
        <label for="question-1-answers-A">A) Computer Styled Sections </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B" />
        <label for="question-1-answers-B">B) Cascading Style Sheets</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-C" value="C" />
        <label for="question-1-answers-C">C) Crazy Solid Shapes</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-D" value="D" />
        <label for="question-1-answers-D">D) None of the above</label>
    </div>
</li>        ....question 2....    <li>
    <h3>CSS Stands for...</h3>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-A" value="A" />
        <label for="question-2-answers-A">A) Computer Styled Sections </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-B" value="B" />
        <label for="question-2-answers-B">B) Cascading Style Sheets</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-C" value="C" />
        <label for="question-2-answers-C">C) Crazy Solid Shapes</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-D" value="D" />
        <label for="question-2-answers-D">D) None of the above</label>
    </div>
</li><input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" /></form>    <?php

    $answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers'];
    $answer2 = $_POST['question-2-answers'];
    $answer3 = $_POST['question-3-answers'];
    $answer4 = $_POST['question-4-answers'];
    $answer5 = $_POST['question-5-answers'];
    $totalCorrect = 0;

    if ($answer1 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer2 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer3 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer4 == "D") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer5) { $totalCorrect++; }

    echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 5 correct</div>";

?>
```

My quiz questions are static i.e. users can do some Googling to answer the questions which I do not want, so I want to generate random questions then score them but don’t know how. I want to make use of database `rand()` questions. I already have this to generate 10 random questions from database:

```
select*from (select*from quiz where level between 1 and 10 order by rand()) tmp group by level order by level
```

So what I need is to score the generated random question. I don’t know how to code it.

Comment: `I don’t know how to code it.` And that's where the problem is. Stack Overflow is ment for programmers that have an issue with their code. Not to find someone to do your job for you. I know it's frustrating to want something but being unable to do it and those who can do it don't want to help you. So sorry if I come across a bit harsh. But try to see it from our point of view: If we do this for you, you won't learn anything. We spend valuable time on it for no reason at all. Cause next time you need something, you just ask again. So start learning!

Comment: And once you've learned, you can do it yourself. No more frustrations. And ofcourse SO will be here when you have a specific problem with your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to understand what you mean, but to include random questions into the quiz, I would build it as follows:
1) Store all the questions, answers, and right answer in a MySQL database table.
2) Have multiple versions of the same question in the database.
3) Have PHP select a random version of the question from the database
4) Load the questions in and build build the HTML for them with PHP.